# Sinon Mocking this.refs

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, sinon, enzyme

Currently unit testing a function that contains this.refs [ data ] in it. Since I can only do shallow rendering, I keep getting undefined. I've tried to mock in sinon by doing

```
var refs = { '001m000000RkzHuAAJ': function () {} };
var refStub = sinon.mock(refs);
```

But I believe because the function is doing this.refs rather than refs it's not working. Any thoughts as to how to mock this.refs?

EDIT:

```
        const wrapper = shallow (
            <CashAllocation receipt={receipt} slds={''} clients={clients} billingStatements={billingStatementswithAllocation} userTitle={'Premium Accounting User'} userPermission={2} />
        );
        wrapper.instance().autoApply();
        wrapper.update();

        console.log(wrapper.state('billingStatements'));
```

What it is calling:

```
autoApply() {
    const clientsSortedbyLargestOutstanding = this.props.clients.slice().sort(function(a,b) {
        if (a.outstandingBalance < b.outstandingBalance) {
            return 1;
        } else if (a.outstandingBalance == b.outstandingBalance) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    });
    var amountToApply = this.state.receipt.Amount_Remaining__c;
    clientsSortedbyLargestOutstanding.forEach(function(client) {
        var amountApplied = 0;
        if (this.state.receipt.Amount_Remaining__c == 0) {
            amountToApply = 0;
        } else {
            if (client.outstandingBalance < (amountToApply + client.currentAllocation)) {
                amountApplied = client.currentAllocation + (client.outstandingBalance - client.currentAllocation);
                amountToApply = amountToApply - (client.outstandingBalance - client.currentAllocation);
            } else {
                amountApplied = client.currentAllocation + amountToApply;
                amountToApply = 0;
            }
        }

        this.refs[ client.Id ].autoApply(amountApplied);
    }, this);
}
```

I get the following error. When i dig through the stack trace its this.refs causing it:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'autoApply' of undefined
```

Comment: There's too little information to go on here. Can you show your test?

Comment: @AndrewEddie see above. let me know if you need any more information